# Safari unable to create Worker from blob due to Content-Security-Policy issue

Tags: safari, blob, web-worker, content-security-policy

I'm trying to create Worker on my web page:

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const worker = new Worker(url);
```

And Safari displays the following error in console:

> Refused to load blob:https://my.address.com/5fa7b5e6-cb10-4b7c-967b-e95cae58cd71 because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

I have the following Content-Security-Policy tag on the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="worker-src 'self' blob:">
```

But looks like Safari ignores it. I bet I tried all possible combinations of SCP directives (such as worker-src, object-src, script-src, child-src, etc.) and sources (*, blob:, 'unsafe-eval', 'unsafe-inline', etc.)

Appreciate any ideas!

**Notes**:

1. When I open my web page in Safari via http Worker is created without any errors. The problem is when opening via https.
2. Worker works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Edge
3. I have only one Content-Security-Policy tag on the page
4. When inspecting Http Response Headers in Safari they look good

Comment: [Works fine for me on Safari 14.0.3](https://csp-safari-blob-worker.glitch.me/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Safari [does not support](https://csplite.com/csp/test234/#safari_worker-src) `worker-src` directive (v 12 was tested) and just ignores it, check the console for `Unrecognized Content Security Policy directive 'worker-src'` message.

Fallback chain for `worker-src` is: `child-src` -> `script-src` -> `default-src`, therefore to support Safari you have to use `child-src` with the same rules as `worker-src`. The `child-src blob:` [works in Safari](https://csplite.com/csp/test236/#test) (push the 'blob:' button to see).

The message `because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy` is unclear. Do you already have `child-src` / `default-src` with some rules in the policy?
Because `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="worker-src 'self' blob:">` just ignores by Safari and should not block worker.

Comment: Indeed, I have this message in console "Unrecognized Content Security Policy directive 'worker-src'", and I didn't pay enough attention to it before. Yes, I have 'default-src' set up (without blob rule) in http response headers. It should explain the reason of my issue. When I added child-src to meta tag nothing changed. It should be because of http response headers have priority over meta tag rules. So, I added child-src to response headers and it resolved my issue 